# How do I find the integral of the product of two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in terms of those two functions?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the integral $\int \left(f(x) × g(x)\right) dx$, where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are arbitrary integrable functions. Without knowing the exact definitions of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, is it possible to expand this integral into some combination of elementary operations, derivatives, and/or integrations of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ WITHOUT having a product of two functions inside an integral?

Googling suggests that I need to use "[Integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)", but everything I can find on that topic requires already being able to evaluate the integral of a product of two functions, without explaining how to go about doing that. Are we limited to numerical methods, or are there symbolic/algebraic methods?

Comment: $f(x)g(x)$ is just another polynomial. Very easy to integrate.

Comment: @KurtG. Your correct observation made me realize that "polynomials" was a much more limited set of functions than I meant to ask about. I updated the question for clarity on that front.

Comment: Let $\int f(x)dx  = F(x)$ and $\int g(x)dx  = G(x)$. If you can somehow represent $f(x)$ as $f(G(x))$ without much hassle, or $g(x)$ to $g(F(x))$, then it is easy, since $d/dx \ \ F(G(x)) = f(G(x))\cdot g(x)$ and so on

Comment: @DS I'm interested in more general cases.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. Integration is pretty much all special cases. There's a reason Gradshteyn and Rhyzhik spends about 8 pages on derivative formulas and 800 on integral ones.